# Having trouble in python functions assignment

Tags: python, function, return

I'm doing Python from codecademy and having trouble in Plan a Vacation assignment (7/7).

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
  return 140*nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
  if city == 'Charlotte':
    return 183
  elif city == 'Tampa':
    return 220
  elif city == 'Pittsburgh':
    return 222
  elif city == 'Los Angeles':
    return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
  cost = days*40
  if days >= 7:
    cost -= 50
  elif days >= 3 and days <7:
    cost -= 20
  return cost

def trip_cost(city,days,spending_money):
  return rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days - 1)+plane_ride_cost(city)+spending_money

city = raw_input('city?')
days = raw_input('days?')
spending_money = raw_input('money?')
print trip_cost(city,days,spending_money)
```

When I run the script and give the input at prompt, it fails showing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 28, in <module>
  File "python", line 23, in trip_cost
  File "python", line 17, in rental_car_cost
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'unicode' and 'int'
```

Comment: Having trouble does not help us help you. What are you having trouble with? Are you getting errors? If you are what are they?

Comment: having trouble - you are vage much. What is your problem exactly, what is your expected outcome for which input parameters and what is the actual output. - also: why tag as [tag:python-3.x] if you use `print` without `()` (and `raw_input()`) and why tag [tag:printf] - both tags are wrong.

Comment: one potential problem is if the input is `tampa` (lowercase) or a city not listed. you will want a default return and also a check for the case of the city/input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string, and you can't do maths with strings. You need to convert the appropriate values to numbers, e.g.:

```
days = int(raw_input('days?'))
spending_money = float(raw_input('money?'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here, but first off, if your assignment allows, I would use a class instead of multiple functions. I would simply create 1 large object. The reason being is that you have so many parameters that it just makes more sense to pass the parameters to the class and then allow the functions to manipulate them rather than pass parameters to multiple functions. Everything is similar since it is all related to a trip, so i'd store it in a class. I am using Python 3.6, so this differs slightly from the Python 2 version you are using, but as you can see I still have to convert user input to integer values. In your code you are not converting user input to integer values, but you are trying to perform mathematical operations on the data. That should give you a traceback as well. You will have to actually define the datatype before raw_input. The input function will not work this way in Python 2 that it does in Python 3.6. But if you've ever coded in Java, it is essentially like declaring a variable. Also, when getting user input here, I would change the cities to evaluate what the value is with the .lower() method. It is risky to trust user with capitalization. I made a few other changes here and hope that it helps.

```
class BigTrip():

   def __init__(self, nights, days, city, spending_money):

      self.nights = nights
      self.days = days
      self.city = city
      self.spending_money = spending_money

   def hotel_cost(self):
      self.hotel_cost = 140 * self.nights
      return "Your hotel cost will be " + str(self.hotel_cost) + " dollars."

   def plane_ride_cost(self):

      if city.lower() == 'charlotte':
          self.plane_cost = 183
      elif city.lower() == 'tampa':
          self.plane_cost = 220
      elif city.lower() == 'pittsburgh':
          self.plane_cost = 222
      elif city.lower() == 'los angeles':
          self.plane_cost = 475
      return "Your plane cost will be " + str(self.plane_cost) + " dollars."

   def rental_car_cost(self):


      self.rental_cost = self.days * 40
      if int(self.days) >= 7:
          self.rental_cost -= 50
      elif int(self.days) >= 3 and int(self.days) <7:
          self.rental_cost -= 20
      return "Your rental car cost will be " + str(self.rental_cost) + " dollars."

   def trip_cost(self):
      return "Your total trip cost will be: {} dollars".format(self.days + self.hotel_cost + self.plane_cost + self.spending_money)


nights = int(input("How many nights will you stay in the city?: "))

city = input('\nSelect a city[Charlotte, Tampa, Pittsburgh or Los Angeles]: ')

days = int(input('How many days will you be staying?: '))

spending_money = int(input('How much spending money do you have?: '))

my_trip = BigTrip(nights, days, city, spending_money)
print(my_trip.hotel_cost())
print(my_trip.plane_ride_cost())
print(my_trip.rental_car_cost())
print(my_trip.trip_cost())
```

Here is your output:

```
How many nights will you stay in the city?: 4
Select a city[Charlotte, Tampa, Pittsburgh or Los Angeles]: charlotte
How many days will you be staying?: 3
How much spending money do you have?: 1200
Your hotel cost will be 560 dollars.
Your plane cost will be 183 dollars.
Your rental car cost will be 100 dollars.
Your total trip cost will be: 1946 dollars
```